# Performing a 'Get Items' action on a list with an 'Image' column causes error: "The required field "My Image" data type is not supported"

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, flow, power-automate, image

Flow was working fine until I added a column of type `Image` to the SharePoint list.

(I was hoping to be able to get the image and send it in an email etc).

But now the Flow fails at the [Get Items](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#get-items) action:

> The required field "My Image" data type is not supported.

Issue should be reproduceable by doing a `Get Items` on any SharePoint list with an `Image` column.

I am using a `Filter Query` in `Get Items`, so that only 1 item is returned, eg:

```
Unique_x0020_Values eq '@{variables('search_string')}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my research, [Image columns](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2020/12/06/all-you-need-to-know-about-new-image-column-type-in-sharepoint-online/) in SharePoint are not returned in the output of the [Get items](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#get-items) action in Power Automate.

However, you can get the Image URL using SharePoint REST API (using [Send an HTTP request to SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#send-an-http-request-to-sharepoint) action) like:

```
https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/SPConnect/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('List Name')/items?$select=Title,LogoImage
```

Where `LogoImage` is internal name of image column. You can get the exact internal name of your image column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

**Sample response**:

```
<m:properties>
    <d:Title>New Power Apps logo looks cool! Really really cool!!</d:Title>
    <d:Image>{
          "fileName": "Power Apps logo.jpg",
          "serverRelativeUrl": "/sites/SPConnect/SiteAssets/Lists/dbc6f551-252b-462f-8002-c8f88d0d12d5/Power%20Apps%20logo.jpg",
          "type": "thumbnail",
          "fieldName": "Image"
      }
    </d:Image>
</m:properties>
```

Where `serverRelativeUrl` is the URL of image which you can use in your Power Automate flow.

---

**Related reading**:

[SharePoint Online: All you need to know about New Image column type](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2020/12/06/all-you-need-to-know-about-new-image-column-type-in-sharepoint-online/)

---

**Further implementation**:

To retrieve a single item's `Image` column value in Power Automate, and add it to an email using the [Send an email (V2)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365/#send-an-email-(v2)) action, you could do something like this:

1. [Send an HTTP request to SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#send-an-http-request-to-sharepoint) (where `EventImage` is internal name of `Image` column):

```
Site Address:  Team Name - https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite  
Method:  GET  
Uri:  _api/web/Lists/getByTitle('Events')/items(@{variables('event_id')})?$select=EventImage
```

2. Initialize a variable with an expression that gets the `fileName` of the image:

```
Name:  event_image_filename
Type:  String   
Value:  json(body('Send_an_HTTP_request_to_SharePoint')?['d']['EventImage'])['fileName']
```

3. [Get file content using path](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#get-file-content-using-path):

```
Site Address:  Team Name - https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite
File Path:  /SiteAssets/Lists/your-list-folder-name-here/@{variables('event_image_filename')}
Infer Content Type:  Yes
```

4. Initialize a variable to create an `<img>` tag from the `base64` of the image file:

```
Name:  event_image_img_tag
Type:  String  
Value:  <img style="display:block;" src="data:image/jpg;base64,@{body('Get_file_content_using_path_-_Event_image')['$content']}" alt="Event Image" border="0" width="300" height="300">
```

5. And then insert the variable in your email's HTML code.

Comment: Thank you, I was just starting to look into this, this is very helpful, I was also wondering if image path could be retrieved from image column through either column formatting or a calculated column,  I will look into that further, but might not be possible.

Comment: Image columns are [supported in JSON formatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#supported-column-types) as well. You can get the URL in JSON like `@currentField.serverRelativeUrl` Check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=in2GTsc6XNk) for more information.

Comment: Wow.  Can you tell me which API docs you use for SharePoint?  I know these:  [Get to know the SharePoint REST service](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-to-know-the-sharepoint-rest-service) and [Complete basic operations using SharePoint REST endpoints](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints) - but they are not as thorough as [Microsoft Graph REST API v1.0 reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/overview?view=graph-rest-1.0).  I want to learn to construct URI's like you.

Comment: I use the same [Microsoft documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/sharepoint) you use & I agree that those are not detailed. For specific requirements, google search and trial & error helps to construct the endpoint URL's.

Comment: Does anyone know if there is an authoritative article that lists ALL the column types that are NOT supported by `Get Items`?  I just stumbled across an error where a required `Location` column produces this error:  `Flow save failed with code 'DynamicOperationRequestClientFailure' and message 'The dynamic operation request to API 'sharepointonline' operation 'GetTable' failed with status code 'BadRequest'. This may indicate invalid input parameters. Error response: { "status": 400, "message": "The required field \"Location\" data type is not supported`

Answer (score 1):

Change the "Require that this column contains information" to "NO" and the issue disappears:

[image]

Comment: The error has gone away but I cannot see the column in the `Raw Outputs` of `Get Items` - is the `Image` column property being returned for you?